# Erro com lambda e campos float

Tags: c#, linq, expressões-lambda

Sempre que carrego minha lambda, me esse erro:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The specified cast from a
>   materialized 'System.Double' type to the 'System.Single' type is not
>   valid.'

Isso só acontece com campos float. Se eu comento os campos e deixo apenas os campos strings, roda normalmente. Veja a classe que implementa a lambda:

```
public class Autoriza
    {
        InetContext contexto = new InetContext();
        Liberacao liberacao = new Liberacao();
        public IEnumerable<object> getAutoriza()
        {
            var lista = contexto.Liberacoes
                .Join(contexto.ItensLibs, lib => lib.IdOrcamento, itens => itens.IdOrcamento, (lib, itens) => new { lib, itens })
                .Where(a => a.lib.IdOrcamento == a.itens.IdOrcamento)
                .Select(libera => new
                {
                    libera.lib.TipoVenda,
                    libera.lib.Vencimento,
                    libera.lib.Juros,
                    libera.lib.Entrada,
                    libera.lib.Acrescimo,
                    libera.lib.Desconto,
                    libera.lib.Mensagem,
                    libera.lib.DataLib,
                    libera.lib.Vendedor,
                    libera.lib.Cliente,
                    libera.lib.Filial,
                    libera.itens.Produto,
                    libera.itens.Qtde,
                    libera.itens.Unitario,
                    libera.itens.Custo,
                    libera.itens.CustoDiario,
                    libera.itens.UltCondicao,
                    libera.itens.Total
                }).ToList();

            return lista;
        }
    }
```

Esta é minha classe de domínio Liberacao:

```
[Table("LIBERACAO")]
    public class Liberacao
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Column("ID_LIBERACAO")]
        public int IdLiberacao { get; set; }
        [Column("FLAG_LIBERACAO")]
        public byte FlagLiberacao { get; set; }
        [Column("ID_ORCAMENTO")]
        public int IdOrcamento { get; set; }
        [Column("ID_VENDEDOR")]
        public int IdVendedor { get; set; }
        [Column("VENDEDOR")]
        public string Vendedor { get; set; }
        [Column("ID_FILIAL")]
        public int IdFilial { get; set; }
        [Column("FILIAL")]
        public string Filial { get; set; }
        [Column("DATALIB")]
        public float DataLib { get; set; }
        [Column("HORALIB")]
        public float HoraLib { get; set; }
        [Column("ID_CLIENTE")]
        public int IdCliente { get; set; }
        [Column("CLIENTE")]
        public string Cliente { get; set; }
        [Column("TIPO_VENDA")]
        public string TipoVenda { get; set; }
        [Column("JUROS")]
        public float Juros { get; set; }
        [Column("DESCONTO")]
        public float Desconto { get; set; }
        [Column("VENCIMENTO")]
        public float Vencimento { get; set; }
        [Column("ACRESCIMO")]
        public float Acrescimo { get; set; }
        [Column("ENTRADA")]
        public float Entrada { get; set; }
        [Column("PRAZO")]
        public float Prazo { get; set; }
        [Column("TOTAL_LIQUIDO")]
        public float TotalLiquido { get; set; }
        [Column("MIN_TOTAL")]
        public float MinTotal { get; set; }
        [Column("USUARIO")]
        public string Usuario { get; set; }
        [Column("CUSTODIARIO")]
        public decimal CustoDiario { get; set; }
        [Column("MAX_COMI")]
        public decimal MaxComi { get; set; }
        [Column("VALOR_COMI")]
        public decimal ValorComi { get; set; }
        [Column("NOVA_COMI")]
        public decimal NovaComi { get; set; }
        [Column("MENSSAGEM")]
        public string Mensagem { get; set; }
        [Column("Menssagem_RET")]
        public string MensagemRet { get; set; }
        [Column("DataRetorno")]
        public decimal DataRetorno { get; set; }
        [Column("HoraRetorno")]
        public decimal HoraRetorno { get; set; }
        [Column("TempoProcesso")]
        public decimal TempoPrecesso { get; set; }
        [Column("Tipo")]
        public int Tipo { get; set; }
        [Column("PROGRAMA")]
        public string Programa { get; set; }
        [Column("NOME_PC")]
        public string NomePc { get; set; }
        [Column("NOME_PROCEDURE")]
        public string NomeProcedure { get; set; }
        [Column("Perc_Juros_Total")]
        public decimal PercJurosTotal { get; set; }
        [Column("FLAG_CULTURAVENCIDA")]
        public byte FlagCulturaVencida { get; set; }
        [Column("CULTURA")]
        public string Cultura { get; set; }
        [Column("CULTURA_VCTO")]
        public int CulturaVcto { get; set; }
        [Column("FLAG_PRORROGADO")]
        public byte FlagProrrogado { get; set; }
        [Column("VALOR_PRORROGADO")]
        public decimal ValorProrrogado { get; set; }
        [Column("DIAS_ATRASO")]
        public int DiasAtrazo { get; set; }
        [Column("ID_VENDEDOR2")]
        public int IdVendedor2 { get; set; }
        [Column("VENDEDOR2")]
        public string Vendedor2 { get; set; }
        [Column("COMISSAO_VEND2")]
        public decimal ComissaoVend2 { get; set; }
        [Column("FLAG_COTACAO")]
        public byte FlagCotacao { get; set; }
        [Column("TipoVenda")]
        public string TipoVenda1 { get; set; }
        [Column("Flag_Receber_Atrasado")]
        public byte FlagReceberAtrazado { get; set; }
        [Column("Autorizou_Receber_Atrasado")]
        public string AutorizouReceberAtrazado { get; set; }

    }
```

e a classe de domínio ITENSLIB

```
[Table("ITENSLIB")]
    public class ItensLib
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Column("ID_ITENSLIB")]
        public int IdItensLib { get; set; }
        [Column("ID_ORCAMENTO")]
        public int IdOrcamento { get; set; }
        [Column("ID_PRODUTO")]        
        public int IdProduto { get; set; }
        [Column("PRODUTO")]
        public string Produto { get; set; }
        [Column("QTDE")]
        public float Qtde { get; set; }
        [Column("UNITARIO")]
        public float Unitario { get; set; }
        [Column("CUSTO")]
        public float Custo { get; set; }
        [Column("MINIMO")]
        public float Minimo { get; set; }
        [Column("TOTAL")]
        public float Total { get; set; }
        [Column("CUSTODIARIO")]
        public decimal CustoDiario { get; set; }
        [Column("FABRICANTE")]
        public string Fabricante { get; set; }
        [Column("ULT_CONDICAO")]
        public decimal UltCondicao { get; set; }
        [Column("PROGRAMA")]
        public string Programa { get; set; }
        [Column("NOME_PC")]
        public string NomePc { get; set; }
        [Column("NOME_PROCEDURE")]
        public string NomeProcedure { get; set; }
        [Column("Flag_Vencido")]
        public byte FlagVencido { get; set; }
        [Column("TipoVenda")]
        public string TipoVenda { get; set; }
        [Column("VENDA_VISTA")]
        public float VendaVista { get; set; }
        [Column("MARGEM_AVISTA")]
        public float MargemAvista { get; set; }
        [Column("QTDE_NEG_AVISTA")]
        public float QtdNegAvista { get; set; }
        [Column("VENDA_PRAZO")]
        public float VendaPrazo { get; set; }
        [Column("PM_PRAZO")]
        public float PmPrazo { get; set; }
        [Column("MARGEM_PRAZO")]
        public float MargemPrazo { get; set; }
        [Column("JUROS_PRAZO")]
        public float JurosPrazo { get; set; }
        [Column("QTDE_PRAZO")]
        public float QtdePrazo { get; set; }
        [Column("VENDA_VISTA_ANT")]
        public float VendaVistaAnt { get; set; }
        [Column("MARGEM_AVISTA_ANT")]
        public float MargemAvistaAnt { get; set; }
        [Column("QTDE_NEG_AVISTA_ANT")]
        public float QtdeNegAvistaAnt { get; set; }
        [Column("VENDA_PRAZO_ANT")]
        public float VendaPrazoAnt { get; set; }
        [Column("PM_PRAZO_ANT")]
        public float PmPrazoAnt { get; set; }
        [Column("MARGEM_PRAZO_ANT")]
        public float MargemPrazoAnt { get; set; }
        [Column("JUROS_PRAZO_ANT")]
        public float JurosPrazoAnt { get; set; }
        [Column("QTDE_PRAZO_ANT")]
        public float QtdePrazoAnt { get; set; }
        [Column("VENDA_VISTA_ANT1")]
        public float VendaVistaAnt1 { get; set; }
        [Column("MARGEM_AVISTA_ANT1")]
        public float MargemAvistaAnt1 { get; set; }
        [Column("QTDE_NEG_AVISTA_ANT1")]
        public float QtdeNegAvistaAnt1 { get; set; }
        [Column("VENDA_PRAZO_ANT1")]
        public float VendaPrazoAnt1 { get; set; }
        [Column("PM_PRAZO_ANT1")]
        public float PmPrazoAnt1 { get; set; }
        [Column("MARGEM_PRAZO_ANT1")]
        public float MargemPrazoAnt1 { get; set; }
        [Column("JUROS_PRAZO_ANT1")]
        public float JurosPrazoAnt1 { get; set; }
        [Column("QTDE_PRAZO_ANT1")]
        public float QtdePrazoAnt1 { get; set; }
    }
```

E a minha controller, onde eu chamo minha m,odel que executa a lambda

```
 public class AutorizaController : ApiController
    {
        Autoriza autoriza = new Autoriza();

        [AcceptVerbs("Get")]
        public IEnumerable<object> getLiberacao()
        {
            return autoriza.getAutoriza().ToList();
        }
    }
```

Essa é a tabela Liberacao com os campos vindo na model. Coloquei apenas a Liberacao, pois eu fiz um teste só com os campos dela e continua com o mesmo erro.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Onde acontece o erro?

Comment: @LINQ, esqueci de colocar a controller que chama, mas já editei o post e coloquei o código da controller.

Comment: Quais são os tipos das colunas (onde no sistema é float) no banco?

Comment: Sim, coloquei os mesmos tipos de campos, exceto para os campos REAL no banco, que na minha classe alterei para decimal.

Answer (score 1):

Os campos do tipo `REAL` não podem ser representados por `decimal`, eles são números com ponto flutuante e, por isso, devem ser representados por um campo `double` ou até mesmo `float`.

Baseei minha resposta pelo que foi dito nos comentários (transcrição abaixo - destaque por mim) porque a pergunta não tinha esta informação.

> "*(...) coloquei os mesmos tipos de campos, **exceto para os campos REAL no banco, que na minha classe alterei para decimal**.*"

Comment: Ok, eu não coloquei isso, porque para esse contexto, nenhum campo decimal está sendo chamado, como eu disse eu comentei todos os campos da tabela/classe ItensLib, ele tem um campo REAL no banco, mas eu comentei para fazer esse teste e o erro persiste.

Comment: @pnet Independente de você "chamar" ou não o campo deve dar erro. Se tentar fazer um simples `contexto.Liberacoes.ToList()` já deve estourar um erro.

Comment: Ok, estou corrigindo isso. É que travou meu VS e já vou testar. Estou jogando tudo para double.

Comment: Fiz as alterações na classe poco, substituindo no banco o que é REAL para o tipo DOUBLE na classe. Fiz isso e mesmo assim, continua o erro. Vou comentar, deixar os campos strings e ir colocando campo a campo

Comment: Observei que com campos Int não dá o problema, apenas quando eu carrego campos float, double ou decimal.

Comment: essa linha na lambda `libera.itens.UltCondicao` no banco é REAL, se coloco double ou float dá o erro, mas se coloco Double, aí funciona, mas se faço isso com os demais, continua o erro.

Comment: Está dando agora esse erro: `The entity or complex type AutorizadorService.Infra.Data.Context.Liberacao' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query`